# Compile template without appending to document with custom scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to compile remote template (template.html file) with some values and to get the resulting html without appending it to the page.Can you give me some advice?

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
        return {
                var htmlcontent = angular.element('<div></div>');
                htmlcontent.load('/template.html');
                var tmpl = $compile(htmlcontent);
                var expectHTML = tmpl({
                      value: "myValue"
                });
        }
    })
```

I need to pass myValue to the template, but I don't want to append it to the scope of myDirective. Also I need the resulting html without appending to the real DOM.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `templateUrl?` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-

Comment: No, I need the html to inject it in iframe window

Comment: Do you have Angular inside `iframe` element?

Comment: No, I don't, it's just dynamically generated iframe where I put some html and then print it.

Comment: What is relation between `myDirective` and iframe? Is directive responsible for creating iframe or iframe content?

Comment: Iframe generation and printing is external library which gets only the content: `Printing.print(expectHTML);`. `myDirective` is responsible for the event handlers, which controll which template to download and compile with proper data.